# Наследование от QSqlTableModel. Qt

Tags: sql, qt, qt5

Есть база данных с несколькими таблицами из которой SQL-запросом берутся нужные строки. Эти строки выводятся в QTableView, но необходимо добавить столбец с чекбоксами, которые отмечены/не отмечены в зависимости от наличия этой строки в другой таблице(проверяется другим SQL-запросом).
Для этого создан класс наследник от QSqlTableModel:

```
QSqlTableModelGroup::QSqlTableModelGroup(QObject *parent) : 

QSqlTableModel(parent)
{

}
Qt::ItemFlags QSqlTableModelGroup::flags(const QModelIndex &idx) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags flgs = QSqlTableModel::flags(idx);
    if(idx.column()==3)
    {
        return (flgs | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
    }
    else
    {
        return (flgs);
    }
}

QVariant QSqlTableModelGroup::data(const QModelIndex &idx,int role) const
{
    if(idx.column()==3)
    {
        if(role==Qt::CheckStateRole)
            return QVariant(static_cast<int>(false));
        if(role==Qt::EditRole)
            return QVariant(static_cast<int>(true));

}
else
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
{
    return QSqlTableModel::data(idx);
}
else
     return   QVariant();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
QSqlQuery query,query2;
        QSqlRecord record;
        QString code_obj;
        QSqlTableModelGroup* model1 = new QSqlTableModelGroup;

        model1->setTable("objects");
        model1->setFilter("class_code='NSIProperties'OR class_code='NSIPropertiesGroup'");
        model1->select();
        model1->insertColumn(3);
       ui->tableView_2->setModel(model1);
        for (int i=0; i<model1->rowCount();i++)
        {
            code_obj=model1->index(i,0).data().toString();
            query.exec("SELECT * FROM links WHERE (parent_object_code="+code+" AND object_code="+code_obj+");");
            while(query.next())
            {
                //Здесь нужно отметить чекбокс с координатами i,3 в таблице
            }
        }
```

В результате получаем столбец с чекбоксами, но как их "отметить" программно и выполнять SQL-запросы при изменении его состояния?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А не проще построить сразу нужный запрос на базе обеих таблиц?

Comment: Возможно! Но остается вопрос, как обработать изменение состояния чекбокса

Comment: Возможно вам придётся переопределить виртуальный метод `setData` и устанавливать значение через него. Он требует `QModelIndex`, который можно получить через  `model1->index(i,3)`